# double sum in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum, double

I have a Mysql table called 'homeworks', and I want to get the total of one row, so I'm using this code to get the result:

```
$homeworks_sum_sqli = "SELECT sum(lhid) AS result FROM homeworks WHERE lhid='".$row['lessons_id']."'";
$homeworks_sum_query = mysqli_query($connect, $homeworks_sum_sqli);
$rowsum = mysqli_fetch_array($homeworks_sum_query);
$sum = $rowsum['result'];
echo "$sum";
```

The problem is the result doubled some rows as you see in the picture!!
[look at the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vU1A.jpg)
How I can solve this?
Thanks :)

Comment: **lhid** column is auto-increment?

Comment: No, It's for lessons id

Comment: __lhid__ is a primary key or unique column?

Comment: No, I just use this column to record lessons id from another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after long search :)

I replaced this code

```
$homeworks_sum_sqli = "SELECT sum(lhid) AS result FROM homeworks WHERE lhid='".$row['lessons_id']."'";
```

into this code

```
$homeworks_sum_sqli = "SELECT COUNT(lhid) AS result FROM homeworks WHERE lhid='".$row['lessons_id']."'";
```

sum -> COUNT

That's it :)